# Why there is an image that says this page is not available on all my blogger posts?

Tags: website-design, blogger, blog

I have my blog for the last couple of years, but it is the first time that I see something like this:
When I am in the main page, each of the posts have a message on top of them that says that the webpage is not available(see image at the bottom of this post). I don't know why is this happening at all.
Ill appreciate your help.
Any ideas?

[image]

**update:**
 Update: I noticed that this doesn't happen in all of the posts, looks like just in the first 2 posts. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong on your blog.Visit you blog from another browser, the error you see may be related to some plugins on your browser.

Comment: I don't know what it was, but now is ok :) 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Blogger/google has put some javascript in your site that generates what looks like +1 buttons. Somehow they have a problem with the website that generates it. It's not giving me that message at the moment, so I guess it's fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand is not due to me? It stills there, is not gone. Is there a way to contact them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to put AdSense ad code, or other Javascript, inside the posts?

If so, there's a bug with the post-editor at the moment, which is messing up the end-quotes at the bottom of the ad-unit code (and I guess other bits of Javascript too).   I've noticed that it causes Chrome displays what you are showing in place of the ad, while IE simply refuses to load the blog-post widget.

The work around is to edit your post in Edit HTML view immediately before publishing, and fix the code problem.   Don't go in to Compose mode again, or Blogger's editor will re-introduce the problem.